# Infinite Scrolling - [Never Click Another Page Number Again!]

Tags: script

### About

Have you ever been reading through a post on a Stack Exchange site with a lot of answers and you had to keep clicking the next page link? Wouldn't it be nice if you didn't have to do that? Well now you don't!

Introducing Infinite Scrolling. Just keep scrolling down the page and the answers from the other pages will automatically appear in order at the bottom. You can continue scrolling right up to the very last answer! Not only that, but the script was carefully tested to make sure that voting and commenting worked flawlessly with the dynamically loaded content.

#### License

This script is released under the [MIT License](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php).

#### Download

Get it from my website here:
http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/userscripts/infinite_scroll.user.js

#### Platform

The script should run on any browser that supports UserScripts and jQuery.

### Contact

I can be reached at `admin@quickmediasolutions.com`

### Code

The code is (of course) written in JavaScript and uses jQuery.

Comment: This is only for answers, right? Not for scrolling pages of questions.

Comment: @xanatos: Yes, just answers at this point.